# Why ifconfig shows a different IP address

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, ethernet, ifconfig

I have Embedded Linux devices connected to a local network via Ethernet cable connection. I access each device via their local IP addresses on subnet `192.168.34.0/24.` For example, one device has `192.168.34.240`.

When I run `ifconfig` on the terminal inside the device, I get different IP addresses beginning with 169 as below. I am confused. Why is this?

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:D0:91:4B:45:C9
          inet addr:169.254.253.217  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:634513 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1318475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:78343668 (74.7 MiB)  TX bytes:399586128 (381.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:24085508 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24085508 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11614050334 (10.8 GiB)  TX bytes:11614050334 (10.8 GiB)
```

Comment: Search for "link-local address". That tells you what it is, but it doesn't answer your question of why.

Answer (score 6):

Because on Linux `ifconfig` uses an obsolete kernel API (ioctl-based) which has been superseded more than 20 years ago (and improved over time) by an other kernel API based on [netlink socket messages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html). Among other limitations of the older API:

- can handle only *one* IPv4 address (though it can handle multiple IPv6 addresses). Even removing this address is done by a kludge: setting the address as 0.0.0.0
- will not provide at the same time the netmask of the address when setting it. So assigning an address usually requires two system calls: one for the (host part of) the address, one to fix its netmask
- handling of more than one IPv4 address is also done with a kludge: so-called alias interfaces (really implemented with a label on an address and not as a separate interface), which are seen like this only by `ifconfig`, not by other parts (route, firewall...).
- as OP shows, additional IP addresses without a label (so configured with the newer API) won't be seen at all by `ifconfig`.

Obviously if there is no address label (which if named correctly would then be displayed as alias interface by `ifconfig`), your network was configured using the newer netlink-based API. So you might even spare embedded space by sticking to newer tools and removing `ifconfig` completely.

```
ip address
```

will display all addresses assigned on all interfaces, including multiple IPv4 addresses if more than one on it.

It's possible to reimplement `ifconfig` using the newer API (there's at least a regular user of UL SE here that did this), but it looks like that upgrading this command (eg: for compatibility with other *NIX) instead of (slowly) replacing it with newer tools wasn't something that interested most Linux developers or distribution maintainers.

So on Linux you should consider using [`ip link`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html) and [`ip address`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-address.8.html) instead of `ifconfig`. Likewise, `ip route` to replace `route`, [`bridge`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/bridge.8.html) (in addition to `ip link`) to replace `brctl` and then other subcommands of [`ip`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) to replace various other commands (for VLANs, tunnels, bond interfaces...).

Now about why there is more than one address. The likely reason is that the device makes use of [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software))/[Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) (equivalent to Apple's Bonjour implementation) to communicate in the LAN and announce features. At the same time it's probably configured with DHCP for standard communication (including to Internet). Zeroconf uses a (non-routable) [IPv4LL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4) address separate from the usual address brought by using DHCP.